# Using precommit hooks and branch protection rules

Tags: git, github, branch

how to work pre commit hooks and make the branch more stable

Comment: git by itself does not have any notion of local security. You can mess around with your git repository as much as you want, *locally*. Instead, what you have to do is apply push restrictions on this branch on your central repository, so that if someone commits directly on this branch and then tries to push, they will be denied and will have to rework their commit into a pull request instead. To do this on github, go into settings, Branches, and apply a "Branch protection rule" to the branch(es) in question.

Comment: What's a direct commit?

Comment: @evolutionxbox I'm assuming it means that someone checked out the branch, committed to it, and then pushes that to the central repository, as opposed to checking out that branch, **creating and checking out a new feature branch**, committing to **that**, and then pushing **that branch** before creating a pull request back to the main branch.

Answer (score 0):

Using precommit hooks you can abort errors in codes that would have been found later. As name suggests it executes before the commit and if that fails user cannot commit their code without rectifying the errors/required validations. It is useful in syntax checking and a lot of other things depending upon use case.
Since it stops the errors before commit and validates the code syntax etc firsthand, it decreases the chances of more error prone code commits and a more stable code for your CICD pipelines.

Using branch protection rules is even more critical, it enables you to ensure that you configure the right way of code acceptance of your project. you can restrict users from merging without reviews. It can also enforce the code to validate certain status checks to pass before allowing a pull request to merge.

In a nutshell both of these features are really required for each medium-large project, with multiple users checking in their code for a stable delivery using your CICD pipeline.